# Запрос данных сервера. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, get

По адресу https://api.coincap.io/v2/assets?limit=1
есть парметр "priceUsd" с числовым значением
пытаюсь получить его в консоль на http://localhost:3000
весь код

```
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer();


server.on('request', (req, res) =>{
    res.end('Hello')
   });

server.listen(3000, (error) => console.log('Server Run'));

server.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    function req() {
        const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", "https://api.coincap.io/v2/assets?limit=1");
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charaset=utf-8");
        request.send();
        request.addEventListener("load" , function() {
            if (request.status == 200) {
                let data = JSON.parse(request.response);
                console.log(data);
                
            } else {
                console.error("Что-то не так");
            }
        });
    }
})
req();
```

Comment: Может я что-то путаю, но откуда на сервере взяться событию "DOMContentLoaded"?

Comment: У вас тут целый винегрет из серверного кода и браузерного.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас смешались браузерный и серверный код.

Вы запускаете код не в браузере. Сервер и браузер - это две разные среды, и код, который работает в одной среде, не обязательно заработает в другой.

По порядку:

- В `node.js` модуле `http`, у класса `http.Server`, инстанс которого вы создаете с помощью метода `http.createServer()`, нет метода `addEventListener()`. Он из браузерного `DOM API`.
- В `node.js` нет такого класса как `XMLHttpRequest`. Он есть в виде отдельно загружаемого **npm модуля**, и в браузерном API. Все реквесты делаются  с помощью метода `http.request()` или других сторонних http-клиентов, например `axios`.
- Ну и у вас функция `req()` объявлена внутри обработчика слушателя. Объявлена и никогда не будет вызвана. Вы пытаетесь вызвать ее в последней строчке, но получите `req is not defined`.

В вашем случае код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```js
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');

const server = http.createServer((_req, res) => { // создаем инстанс класса http.Server
    
    // при запросе к localhost:3000 выполнится этот колбэк  

    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' }); 
    

    // опции запроса к удаленному серверу
    const options = {
        host: 'api.coincap.io',
        path: '/v2/assets?limit=1',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
      };
  
    // http запрос вернет нам 301 Permanently Moved, поэтому https
    https.request(options, (response) => {
        let str = '';
        
        // данные грузятся не одним куском, а чанками
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            str += chunk;
        });
        
        response.on('end', function () {
            const { priceUsd } = JSON.parse(str).data[0]; // получаем preiceUsd из ответа
            
            res.end(priceUsd); // отправляем ответ тому, кто обратился к localhost:3000
        });
    }).end();
  });

server.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
```

Добавил может быть кривоватые комменты в код, но старался, чтобы было понятно, что и для чего.

Вообще поподробнее изучите:

- [Документацию](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) по модулю `http`
- [Всё что нужно знать про HTTP](https://medium.com/@twanttobealighi/%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%91-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-http-75567dad34c)

И если хотите работать с бэкендом, лучше начните с фреймворка типа [express.js](https://expressjs.com/ru/), чтобы не изобретать велосипед.

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Особенно за коментари.

Comment: Я не слишком разобрался в отличиях и в том что есть сразу в node.js 
 и смешал куски react , xhr и GET.

Comment: А как изменить код чтобы при запросе http://localhost:3000/rates?currency=" id " получать параметр "priceUsd" об любой из 100 пердставленіх на сервере монет.
Каким лучше методом это сделать fetch ;  react+ useState ;  XMLHttpRequest.
Браузеры актуальные не устаревшие.

Comment: или использовать Axios 
' import axios from 'axios';
const axios = require("axios");
const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.coincap.io/v2/assets?',
  params: {category: 'id', count: 'str'},
  headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',  }
};

axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
 console.log(response.data);
}).catch(function (error) {
 console.error(error);
});
'

Comment: @SiriusBlek это все отдельные вопросы. Используйте ``express.js`` и ``axios`` и не парьтесь. Только документацию читайте к ним.